# OpenCV - VideoWriter FPS

Tags: video-processing, opencv, python

I'm building a script to overlay bounding boxes onto my video via a CSV file. Each frame has n number of bounding boxes, and so I am just iterating over the bounding boxes in each frame and drawing a `cv2.rectangle` on the frame. As a result, I am writing to a frame many times, for all frames.

While my VideoWriter constructor takes in 23.97 FPS as a parameter, the resulting FPS is much lower. Is there an algorithm or a way in which I can set a proper FPS to compensate for the FPS drop after writing to the video?

Below is my code-snippet:

```
avg_fws = counter_written/float(total_frames-1)
width = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('data/bounding_videos/%s.avi' % video_file, fourcc, fps * avg_fws, (width,height))
counter = 1
print (counter_written)
while (video.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = video.read()
    if ret == True:
        if len(frames_dict) != 0:
            for i in frames_dict[counter].keys():
                box_dim = frames_dict[counter][i]
                x, y, w, h = box_dim
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 255, 255), 3)
                out.write(frame)
        else:   
            out.write(frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):                                                                           
            break                                                                                                       
    else:                                                                                                               
        break                                                                                                           
    counter += 1                                                                                                        
video.release()                                                                                                         
out.release()                                                                                                           
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The counters are just for me to keep track / access the frames, and `avg_fws` is the average frames written per second which basically is `total_num_of_frames_written / total_num_of_frames_in_video`.

Comment: It may be possible that you are writing the same frame multiple times, hence giving an illusion of low FPS. I would recommend you to attach a code snippet.

Comment: @ZdaR I've added a code snippet. And yes, I am writing to the same frame multiple times. What do you mean by an illusion of low FPS?

Comment: Just move the `out.write(frame)` outside the `for` loop to avoid re writing same frame.

Comment: @ZdaR thanks so much, that worked! will post your solution as an answer.

Comment: Yeah sure done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that, you are writing multiple frames in your `for` loop for each rectangle drawn. What you need to do is draw all rectangles at once on a frame and write it only for a single time. It can be done by moving `out.write(frame)` out of your `for` loop.